# How to activate profile by means of maven property?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I'm trying to activate a maven profile using a property defined inside `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <run.it>true</run.it>
  </properties>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <property><name>run.it</name></property>
      </activation>
      [...]
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  [...]
</project>
```

Apparently it doesn't work. However, activation works from the command line:

```
mvn -Drun.it
```

Is it "by design"? If it is, what is a possible workaround?

Comment: Here is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14386303/290918

Comment: I have created a feature request that would add the `<activeProfiles>` tag from the `settings.xml` to `pom.xml` so that you can define profiles you want to activate. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6000

Answer (score 29):

Edit, complete rewrite, as i understand the question now.

See [this forum post](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Activating-a-profile-in-settings-xml-based-on-a-property-set-in-pom-xml-td512562.html):

> profile activation is based on *SYSTEM* properties. 
>   you cannot activate profiles based on properties defined in your pom 
>   you cannot activate profiles based on system properties defined after the 
>   build plan has started execution

Comment: Could you please review the question again? I'm trying to activate the profile with a property defined inside `pom.xml`, not in the command line.

Comment: indeed i missed this, see activeByDefault as M. Jessup told

Comment: Thanks, now I understand that it is "by design". Can you suggest a workaround please?

Answer (score 6):

What about using an activation like this

```
    <profile>
        <id>gwt</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>uses-gwt.marker</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
```

and adding the file 'uses-gwt.marker' into source control, right next to pom.xml. That gives all developers the same state and sort of allows an aspect-oriented pom. we're using this technique in the parent pom and put hte marker files in the childs svn. Not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 5):

In recent maven versions (3.5+?) you can create a `.mvn` folder at the root of your project and a file `.mvn/maven.config`. In this file you can then activate profiles or set properties as you would do on the command line.

activate a profile through a property:

```
-Dactivate.myprofile=true
```

activate a profile directly

```
-Pmyprofile
```

Hopefully maven5 will get support for Mixins, which will probably make build settings more reusable.

Comment: Thank you, this made my day! I needed to be able to configure a child project to enable a profile from the parent POM that didn't require extraneous args in the command line.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in previous answers, profile activation only works with system properties.

But, with a little creativity you can achieve a similar result (conditional plugin execution) using pom properties. To achieve that, use the phase tag of the plugin you want to conditionally execute:

```
<project>

    ...

    <properties>
        <run.it>none</run.it>
        <!-- <run.it>compile</run.it> -->
        <!-- <run.it>package</run.it> -->
    </properties>

    ...

    <build>

        ...

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>your-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>${run.it}</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        ...

    </build>

</project>
```

The only difference is that you have to use a phase name instead of true/false. But you can change the property or override it freely as a property.

Answer (score 2):

- Add a directory ".mvn" to your project root.
- Add a file ".mvn/jvm.config"
- Insert "-Drun.it=false" into jvm.config.

Now it should work. You can overwrite the "run.it" property in your pom.xml and it will be picked up for profile activation.

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score -2):

As Moritz Heuser explained, profile activation is based on **system** properties. However, you can *try* something like that:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <run.it>true</run.it>
  </properties>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>${run.it}</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      ...
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
</project>
```

The idea is to define the `activeByDefault` flag in the `<properties>`.

Comment: I don't see how this helps.  Defining run.it in the pom is too late for the profile to take effect.  Per https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5235

Comment: I agree. There is a classical chicken-and-egg problem: profiles my their nature may define other properties. Should they also activate other profiles recursively? What if profile was already activated but new property definition instructs to deactivate it?

Comment: This does not work for the same reason the OP's example doesn't work (as explained by @moritz)

Answer (score -3):

I think your question is similar to this one.

[Activation of maven profile based on multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417437/activation-of-maven-profile-based-on-multiple-properties/5418467#5418467)

As mentioned, you can activate a profile and set various properties as per your requirement and use command `mvn -Prun-it` to set property to true .

```
<project>
  [...]

  [...]
  <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>don't-run</id>
<properties>
    <run.it>false</run.it>
  </properties>


      [...]
    </profile>


    <profile>
    <id>run-it</id>
<properties>
    <run.it>true</run.it>
  </properties>

      [...]
    </profile>


  </profiles>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Kindly review my question. I'm interested to turn the profile on/off from inside `pom.xml`, not from command line or `settings.xml`.

Comment: But how does it make any difference to you, can you elaborate please?
Also, as mentioned by Moritz, activation is done based on system property and not by command line. See this reference http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html