# What is the difference between mvn clean install -Drelease-build and mvn clean install?

Tags: maven

I need to know what is the difference between these two commands which do almost same thing if we execute this command.

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't assign any special meaning to `release-build`. However, projects can use properties (`-Dproperty-name=value` or just `-Dproperty-name`) to activate profiles that change the way the project is built ([Maven - activate profile based on project property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889554/maven-activate-profile-based-on-project-property)). It's likely to enable some extra steps that are only necessary for final releases. For example, [this project uses it to include a native library in the build](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/f570ac160f8f40431585d80496438c8638e4f76a/pom.xml#L157):

```
<profile>
    <id>native</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>release-build</name>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>pi4j-native</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

There's no general answer: you'll need to consult the documentation, or build, of the project you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this much more simpler automatically [to activate a profile in case of a release](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) simply via the maven-release-plugin which already supports that out-of-the-box like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Apart from that it's really bad to acitvate a module only in case of a profile is active. [This will lead so several problem.](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/)