# Do Maven project properties have write-once semantics

Tags: maven

I observed a Maven behavior today that left me puzzled. Either the project properties have some sort of write-once semantics or... I failed to find any reference documentation that would explain this behavior.

Can I dynamically set Maven properties in the validate phase to have them evaluated as plugin properties in later phases?

**Goal**

I want to skip the execution of a plugin in a profile based on the existence of some other property.

**Plan**

1. Run the Groovy plugin in the `validate` phase.
2. Evaluate the existence of that other property.
3. Set the skip project property.
4. Use the skip property for the configuration of plugins that run in later phases.

**POM excerpt**

```
<profile>
    <id>my-id</id>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>${basedir}/somefile</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <skipIt>false</skipIt> <!-- intention: use this as default value -->
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <scripts>
                                <script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                def someOtherProp = project.properties['some-other-property']
                                def skipIt = someOtherProp ? 'false' : 'true'
                                project.properties['skipIt'] = skipIt
                                println skipIt
                                println project.properties['skipIt']
                                ]]>
                                </script>
                            </scripts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipIt}</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>my-unpack</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
```

**Behavior**

If `some-other-property` does not exist (i.e. is not set) this prints `true` twice. That means the Groovy evaluation is correct and `skipIt` was correctly set. Yet, the dependency-plugin still runs the `my-unpack` execution. Why?

However, if I remove `<skipIt>false</skipIt>` on line 9 everything works as I expect. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - activate profile based on project property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889554/maven-activate-profile-based-on-project-property)

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question AFAICS (other than Maven, profiles, and properties being involved).

Comment: Does the gmavenplus-plugin actually change the project properties or only some copy of it?

Comment: @JFabianMeier good thinking! However, if it were operating on a copy then the behavior wouldn't change if I remove `<skipIt>false</skipIt>`, would it?