# How do I invoke two different profiles in one maven command?

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles

I have two profiles for different environments in `pom.xml`, I have to run `mvn -PTest1 install` and `mvn -PTest2 install` command to get these profiles in use. Can we integrate two separate maven commands in a single one (like `mvn clean install`)?

Here is my Pom entry

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>Test1</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    <jdk>1.5</jdk>
    <os>
       <name>Windows XP</name>
       <family>Windows</family>
       <arch>x86</arch>
       <version>5.1.2600</version>
    </os>
    <property>
       <name>sparrow-type</name>
       <value>African</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>
      com.endeca
      </groupId>
      <artifactId>
      endeca_navigation_Test1
      </artifactId>
     <version>
     6.1
     </version>
     <!--<version>stable</version> -->
    <scope>
    compile
    </scope>
  </dependency>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>Test2</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      <jdk>1.5</jdk>
      <os>
        <name>Windows XP</name>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
        <version>5.1.2600</version>
      </os>
      <property>
        <name>sparrow-type</name>
        <value>African</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>
        com.endeca
        </groupId>
        <artifactId>
        endeca_navigation_Test2
        </artifactId>
        <version>
        6.1
        </version>
        <!--<version>stable</version> -->
        <scope>
        compile
        </scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

It will helpfull to manage hudson job using single command

Comment: So you want to combine commands  `mvn -PTest1 install` and `mvn -PTest2 install`?

Comment: I need to integrate these two commands mvn -PTest1 install and mvn -PTest2 install with my Hudson job command mvn install. The mvn install is handling with Hudson job for our project.

Answer (score 110):

Based on the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and discussion [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-profile-execution-in-maven-td2700693.html), try separating profile names with a comma:

```
mvn install -P Test1,Test2
```

Comment: the link to discussion is dead 

Answer (score 33):

[Mifeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792775/1429387) is correct, but in Windows PowerShell you should quote parameters, otherwise you'll get "unknown lifecycle phase" error.

```
mvn install -P 'Test1,Test2'
```

Comment: For me it is `"` `"` , I am using cmd

Answer (score 27):

For me Mifeet's answer isn't working. I get "unknown lifecycle phase Test2". For me this is working:

```
mvn install -PTest1 -PTest2
```

Comment: Are you using PowerShell? See naXa's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the maven help command

```
 -P,--activate-profiles <arg>   Comma-delimited list of profiles to activate
```

So you can run `mvn package -Pp1,p2` to run profile id with p1 and p2