# Jenkins: Pass multiple MAVEN profiles via user selection

Tags: maven, jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

following situation: I want to build a maven project via jenkins and also be able to select multiple maven profiles (to be precise it has to build with two profiles, one of those is a fixed value called 'dev', so basically I want to be able to select the second profile from a list of profiles) before building, so a parameterized build. I add the selectable profile as a option-list and now I'm able to select it from a dropdown, so far, so good.

BUT: It seems the problem is the multiple profile part.

In the maven goal-field I type

`clean install -Pdev,$Client`

with 'Client' being the parameter for the build which contains the selected value.

But if I start the build, the command line says e.g.

```
mvn clean install "-Pdev,test"
```

with the problem being it wrapping the Profiles in apostrophes. If I test it with a single parameter it works as expected:

```
clean install -P$Client
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following explanation, try some of these:

```
#1    mvn install -P profile1,profile2
#2    mvn install -Pprofile1 -Pprofile2
#3    mvn install -P 'profile1,profile2'
```

## Explanation

According to official documentation

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

The correct multi profile invocation is :

`mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P profile1,profile2`

And some variations are allowed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792775/3957754
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42766252/3957754

`mvn install -Pprofile1 -Pprofile2`

Ans as always :s an special treatment for windows:

`mvn install -P 'profile1,profile2'`

Comment: As I've said in my Post, I already tried the usual "-Pprofile1,profile2", but it doesn't work... I also tried the variant "-Pprofile1 -Pprofile2.

Comment: Your **usual** "-Pprofile1,profile2" is **wrong**. It is similar to #1 but you need to examined in detail. I tried and worked.

Comment: ? I don't understand. I tried every combination, it doesn't work if I use one dynamic and one fix profile, no matter if I wrap them in no, single or double quotes. What I meant with "usual" is that it's the normal way to call

mvn clean install 

with multiple profiles!

Comment: Could you share us a maven project (hello world) in github and screenshots or how are configured your jenkins? Maybe is a jenkins version issue :s