# Activate 2 build profile on maven via command

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

how should looks like the output of the command that works I try this

```
mvn test -P 'test,normal'
```

and I think it works only show this messages strange (for me, I've started to learn maven recently)

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "'test" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "normal'" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

so, the question is how do I identy that already run both profiles?

When I run the command with double quotes doesn't show the warnings but I think that only execute the *normal* profile, because it shows

```
[INFO] Executing tasks
 [echo] Using env.properties
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

Something similar occurs when I run commands that follow

```
mvn test -Ptest -Pnormal
mvn test -Ptest,normal
```

So I am not sure how should be look. Thanks for your help. I base on this discussion
[How do I invoke two different profiles in one maven command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792499/how-do-i-invoke-two-different-profiles-in-one-maven-command/70896769#70896769)

Comment: The linked answer is correct. Its -Pa,b But based on shell you would need a quote. But the otuput from your first try is correct and shows the pom.xml did not have the profiles with the name. So probally something not correct how you defined the profiles.

Comment: Yes, I change the names of the profiles, and I try everyone standalone and it works. So, I expected the two outputs where I run the command with both profiles, but I don't know, if its correct.